# Ação ImageView em ListView

Tags: android

Boa noite,

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para android, e tenho na minha tela principal um ListView e uma Activity com dois ImageView e um TextView, essa essa Activity é chamada na classe principal que controla do ListView, até aí tudo certo.

O que eu gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com que um dos ImageView quando clicado (já que pertence ao ListView), pegasse o id do ListView na sua ação de onClick.

Alguém sabe se isso é possivel?

Segue os códigos:

Tela principal onde tem o **ListView**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity"
>

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >




    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPlacas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:divider="#FFFFFF"
        android:dividerHeight="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@drawable/fundo_list"
        />


</FrameLayout>

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="checklist.system.cooper.br.syschecklist.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Tela onde tem os **itens** do **ListView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<View
    android:id="@+id/Vbarra"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_width="335dp"
    android:background="#3929769f"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemview"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/checklist"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/txtPlacaPrincipal"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="0"
        android:id="@+id/txtQuantidade"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagemAdd"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add_to_queue"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="addCheckList"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Código da **chamada do ImageView**

```
public void addCheckList(View v)
{

}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Tenta seguir esse tutorial: http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/. Com ele eu consegui fazer áreas clicáveis dentro de um item no `ListView`

Answer (score 2):

Tente isso

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o evento de clique no adapter da sua listView:

Veja se isso te ajuda.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.itemlistrow, null);

    }

        final Item item = getItem(position);

        TextView txtQuantidade = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantidade);
        TextView txtPlacaPrincipal= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtPlacaPrincipal);
        ImageView imagemAdd= (ImageView )v.findViewById(R.id.imagemAdd);

         txtQuantidade.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQtde());
         txtPlacaPrincipal.setText(item.getPlacaPrincipal());

        imagemAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             //evento

         } 
           });




    return v;

}
```

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa situação?

Comment: Isso que postei não lhe ajudou? Qual o problema?